# Eigenvalues of the Schur complement

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices, schur-complement

For a symmetric invertible block matrix such as below, is there a relation between the eigenvalues of $M$ and that of the Schur complements and the matrices in the diagonal?

\begin{align}
M = \begin{bmatrix}A & B \\ B^T & C\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from the [Haynsworth inertia additivity formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haynsworth_inertia_additivity_formula)

$$ 
\text{In}(M)=\text{In}(C)+\text{In}(\underbrace{A-BC^{-1}B^T}_{M~\setminus~ C})=\text{In}(A)+\text{In}(\underbrace{C-B^TA^{-1}B}_{M~\setminus~ A})
$$

where $\text{In}()$ denotes the inertia (ordered set of the count of positive, negative and zero eigenvalues of a matrix).

Comment: what is inertia?

Comment: Please refer to the hyperlink I added to the updated answer. It means the ordered set of the count of positive, negative and zero eigenvalues of a matrix.

Comment: I don't understand what is the addition of "inertias" here? Are the sets added component-wise?